# F.when(~F.col('text').like('\bfoo\b') not working as expected in PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Why is this part `(~F.col('text').rlike('\bfoo\b')` not working?

**UPDATED:**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
    
df = spark.createDataFrame(['Some text with foo and more text','Some text with bar and more text'],['value_1',None], "string").toDF("text", "check")
            
df_new = df.withColumn('check', F.when(((F.col('text').isNotNull()) & \
                                        (F.col('check').isNull() & \
                                        (~F.col('text').rlike('\bfoo\b')), 
                                my_udf(F.col('text'))) \
.otherwise(F.col('check'))
            
df_new.show(truncate=False)
+----------------------------------------+
|text                            |check  |
+--------------------------------+-------|
|Some text with foo and more text|value_1|
|Some text with bar and more text|       |
+--------------------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `rlike` instead to use regex :

```
df_new = df.withColumn('check', ~F.col('text').rlike(r'\bfoo\b'))

df_new.show(truncate=False)
#+--------------------------------+-----+
#|text                            |check|
#+--------------------------------+-----+
#|Some text with foo and more text|false|
#|Some text with bar and more text|true |
#+--------------------------------+-----+
```

And there is no need to use `when` here, `rlike/like` already returns a boolean value.